# Lambda, MongoDB, Cloudfront, and S3 stacks keep giving me timed out error (CORS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

Our platform is built up with Lambda, MongoDB, cloudfront, and s3 stacks. We are using s3 for static hosting. (S3 has CORS configuration) Currently, we are experiencing very weird errors.

**Occasionally**, our platform is getting CORS error in the Front-end.

The CORS error happens mostly (not always) like this pattern.

1. MongoDB connectDB gets undefined (We use a global variable for Mongo connection in Lambda)
   [image]
2. 5~6 Requests are successful
3. Timed out error
4. CORS error in the front - end (No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" ...)
   [image]

Additionally, we put Access-Control-Allow-Origin in our response but the response with CORS error happens occasionally. (Works well most of the time)

So far, we found these from our logs and still cannot figure out to rid of CORS error from our project. Again, this happens occasionally.

Comment: Hi Brandon! I don't know the architecture of your system and there's no code to analyse. So, you didn't mention any [CORS setup in a S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors). If this comment was helpful, don't foget upvoting it.

Comment: Thank you! We have tried to set the CORS in the S3 buckets but it did not work.

Comment: Seems like you have a timeout in your logs. Maybe the task returns an error and in that case there are no CORS headers added?

Comment: @TamásSallai Occasionally, server returns CORS error. We analyzed why it gets timed out error but we could find nothing because most of the time same api requests are working very well. Also, in the return of our handler, it has CORS headers added. Thanks for your comment!